# Attempt to de-reference a null object with Attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, salesforce-id, null-pointer

I am trying to add a attachment to a record. Their may or may not be attachment. So that i have created a attachment in the controller if the attachment is null but i am getting null point exception. 
EXCEPTION_THROWN|[74]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

my code

```
<apex:form > 
 <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="6" >
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput" />
         <apex:inputFile value="{!Attachment.body}" id="fileInput" filename=" {!Attachment.name}" dir="RTL" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    public Attachment attachment;
 public Attachment getAttachment() 
 {
     system.debug('Result : In attachment get () ');
     if(attachment == null) 
             attachment = new Attachment();
     return attachment;
 }
 if(exp.Receipt_Attached__c == true && attachment.body == null)
        {
             ApexPages.Message attMsg = new  ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Expense Receipt is Required.'); 
            ApexPages.addMessage(attMsg); 
            return null;
        }
         system.debug('Result : attachment '+ attachment); 
         if( attachment.body != null) 
         {
            exp.Receipt_Attached__c=true;
         }
```

I am getting error on this line of code if( attachment.body != null).

Comment: If attachment is null, attachment.body will throw a NullPointerException. Check if (attachment!=null && attachment.body!=null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I have solved it. It was issue of the declaration of apex:form. The button i declared  was in the another form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the value in the page as '**value="{!Attachment.body}"**', create a blob variable in the controller named "**AttachmentBody**" and bind the blob value to the page as shown below. And assign the blob value to the attachment.body if the blob is not equal to null.

Controller:

```
Public blob AttachmentBody {get;set;} // For binding to page
public Attachment att 
{
    get 
    {
        if (att == null) att = new Attachment();
        return att;
    }
    set;   
}
att.body = AttachmentBody;
```

Page:

```
<apex:inputFile id="addFile" accept="doc,docx,pdf,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx" value="{!AttachmentBody}" title="Upload Word, Excel, PDF or PowerPoint" filename="{!AttachmentFilename}"  styleClass="forIpText docListStyle3 TextPriority7" />
```

Comment: i don't know why this error is not getting fixed. I have also tried a lot of time but .

Comment: Try this! Replace the code "if( attachment.body != null) " as "if( attachment!= null && attachment.body != null) "

Comment: ya i did it but the get set method is not get invoked. Do you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Attachment, set the body attribute to a non-null value initially:

```
if(attachment == null) {
    attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.body = Blob.valueOf('');
}    
return attachment;
```